# Transform expression into a certain standard form for an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation

I'm using Mathmatica 11.1 on Windows.

Given an expression containing a differntial equation of the form

$\qquad A\, x'(z) = C\, x''(z) - B\, x(z)$

Or

```
A x'[z] == -B x[z] + C x''[z]
```

I want to transform the expression into a standard form for an ODE, namely,

$\qquad x''(z)-\frac{A}{C}x'(z)-\frac{B}{C}x(z)=0$

Or

```
x''[z] - A/C x'[z] - B/C x[z] == 0
```

---

A more generalized version of this format may be represented as

$\qquad y^n(x)-a_{1}\cdot y^{n-1}(x)\cdots a_{n-1}\cdot y'(x)-a_{n}\cdot y(x)=0$

for linear ODEs, or

$\qquad y^n(x)-a_{1}\cdot y^{n-1}(x)\cdots a_{n-1}\cdot y'(x)-a_{n}\cdot y(x)=p(x)$

for non-linear ODES, where $p(x)$ may be some non-linear function on x, such as $sin(x)$ or $1/x$.

---

I have attempted to address this by using [StandardForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html) and [NonlinearStateSpaceModel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html), amongst other ways, and have not yet been able to convert the expression.

I would prefer a solution that is generalized and would function for any given ODE however, this may or may not be practical.

---

Comment: Generalized, including nonlinear equations? E.g. `Apply[Equal, Solve[a x'[z] == -b x[z] + c x''[z]^2, {x''[z]}], {2}]` -- is it how you'd like?

Comment: @MichaelE2, no, that does not present the format that I am looking for

Comment: What would be the desired form in that case, given that it's nonlinear?

Comment: @MichaelE2, I have added some clarifications to the question, but generally, if the ODE is non-linear, then the non-linear aspect of the equation should be moved to the RHS of the expression.

Comment: The term linear applied to ODE usually means the equation is linear in the "dependent variables" $y(x)$ and its derivatives, that is, an equation of the form $\sum a_k(x) y^{(k)}(x) = p(x)$; the coefficients $a_k(x)$ and $p(x)$ may be any functions of $x$. Nonlinear equations have dependent variables in nonlinear functions such as $\sin(y(x))$ or `x''[z]^2`. It seems you are considering only the special case of linear ODES with constant coefficients, not any given ODE such as the one in my comment. That's fine; I just wanted to know since the accepted answer deals only with this special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little clunky, but this should work pretty generally:

```
standardForm[eqn_Equal] := Module[{equation = # - eqn[[1]] & /@ eqn},
  equation = Collect[#, _''[_]] & /@ equation;
  #/First@Cases[equation, a_ _''[_] :> a, Infinity] & /@ equation // Apart // Expand
 ]
```

**Note**: as of V11.3, `# - eqn[[1]] & /@ eqn` can be replaced with `SubtractSides[eqn, First@eqn]`.

Then,

```
standardForm[a x'[z] == -c x''[z] - b x[z] + d x''[z]]
(* 0 == (b*x[z])/(c - d) + (a*Derivative[1][x][z])/(c - d) + Derivative[2][x][z] *)
```

---

**Explanation:**

In the first step,

```
eqn = a x'[z] == -c x''[z] - b x[z] + d x''[z];
equation = # - eqn[[1]] & /@ eqn
(* 0 == -b x[z] - a x'[z] - c x''[z] + d x''[z] *)
```

we move everything to the right-hand side.  In the second step,

```
equation = Collect[#, _''[_]] & /@ equation
(* 0 == -b x[z] - a x'[z] + (-c + d) x''[z] *)
```

we collect all the instances of `x''[z]` so that we can extract the coefficient in the next step,

```
First@Cases[equation, a_ _''[_] :> a, Infinity]
(* -c + d *)
```

in order to then divide both sides of the equation by this value:

```
#/First@Cases[equation, a_ _''[_] :> a, Infinity] & /@ equation // Apart // Expand
(* 0 == b x[z]/(c - d) + a x'[z]/(c - d) + x''[z] *)
```

The `// Apart // Expand` is there to make sure that the cancellation occurs in the coefficient of the `x''[z]` term.

Comment: @TaylorScott.  Added some explanation.

Comment: That's a perfect explanation, thank you :)

Comment: As of V11.3 we have `SubtractSides[eqn, First@eqn]`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, easily generalized for linear ODEs:

```
depvars = NestList[D[#, z] &, x[z], 2]; (* {x[z], x'[z], x''[z]} *)
ca = CoefficientArrays[
   Subtract @@ Solve[a x'[z] == -b x[z] + c x''[z] + p[z], x''[z]][[1, 1]],
   depvars];
Last@ca.depvars == -First@ca
(*  -((b x[z])/c) - (a x'[z])/c + x''[z] == -(p[z]/c)  *)
```